# Set framerate of moving view

Tags: java, android, view

I have a custom view which is being invalidates and moved in his onDraw method, but I want to control the speed, the problem is that if I use Thread.sleep(), it stops the whole app.

Comment: use an Animator,  eg ValueAnimator

Comment: aren't there better solutions, I don't want to use any animator classes...

Comment: *"aren't there better solutions..."* then using an API which is designed to perform animation for you and which is been optimised for the running platform? That sounds a bit weird, I think you need to justify that statement

Comment: You should really read about ValueAnimator,  since it seems you have little idea what it is about

Comment: And there is no solution without ready made classes ?

Comment: "ready made class"? what you mean?

Comment: I am sure it works with separate threads and handlers as well, but it doesn't seem a comfortable and good solutions.

Comment: I mean I am looking for a solution without any Android helping classes and animators.

Comment: If you want to do it by your hands,  use a Handler then...

Comment: oh ok ... thanks... some working code would be really nice, but thanks though :)

Comment: let your View implements Handler.Callback, then create a new Handler(this) and call handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed, in Callback invalidate()

Comment: let your View implements Handler.Callback, then create a new Handler(this) and call handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed, in Callback invalidate() and send message again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62899/discussion-between-pskink-and--).